# Coverflow/3D slider jQuery plugin

Tags: looking-for-a-script, jquery, plugin

I'm looking for a showcase jQuery plugin like this theme at:

http://themeforest.net/item/showtime-business-and-portfolio-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/117367

It shows the focused image in the middle. It's the biggest. On the left or right there are smaller images and it flippes between them on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these:

- [jCoverflip](http://www.jcoverflip.com/demo)
- [Sliding Image gallery](http://www.meadmiracle.com/SlidingGalleryDemo1.htm) (download [here](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/SlidingGallery))
- [Imageflow](http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/)
- [jQuery UI coverflow](http://addyosmani.com/blog/jqueryuicoverflow/)
- [Contentflow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/)